# Shorten and change existing code in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I need to make a shorter version of the code below:

```
val y = 42
val x = "Score" + (y + 4).toString ()
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Why shorter?  Is this for a limited embedded device?  Or is this a learning exercise, or a homework problem?

Answer (score 4):

You may use string interpolation:

```
val x = "Score${y + 4}"
```